# How to delete registry entry with batch command?

Tags: windows, registry

I want to delete a specific entry in registry. The path is this

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\3rdparty\Extensions\heildphpnddilhkemkielfhnkaagiabh\policy\url_list
```

Then in the path, there is a specific entry with name `4` and entry `server.com`.

I found this

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SomeProgram" /v "EntryName"
```

but how do I get it to delete by value? I want to enter `server.com` instead of `4`.

Answer (score 0):

The command line allows just the deletion of keys but not their values.You can use an alternative by overwriting the value by what you want

Use :

```
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\3rdparty\Extensions\heildphpnddilhkemkielfhnkaagiabh\policy\url_list /v "EntryName" /t REG_SZ /d example.com
```